# Java: StringBuilder, static method and possible synchronization issues

Tags: java, string

Is it possible for code like this to be not thread safe?  It is a static method and we are using an local instance of stringbuilder.  I guess the input strings might be held by other objects?

```
public static String cat(final String ... strings) {

    ...
    ...
    final StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(totLength);
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {        
        if (strings[i] != null) {
            sb.append(strings[i]);
        }
    }
    return sb.toString();
}
```

Answer (score 11):

It's not fully thread safe - because another thread might be changing the same array that was passed in the argument for the `strings` parameter. This isn't entirely obvious because of your use of varargs, but effectively (in terms of thread safety) the method signature is just:

```
public static String cat(String[] strings)
```

It won't cause any exceptions, but you may not see the latest values within the array.

As another alternative, you *might* see something unexpected if it *does* see the change. For example, suppose we pass in just a single-valued array where the value is initially "x":

```
public static String cat(final String ... strings) {    
    ...
    ...
    final StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(totLength);
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        // strings[0] is currently "x"
        if (strings[i] != null) {
            // But now another thread might change it to null!
            // At that point we'd get "null" as output
            sb.append(strings[i]);
        }
    }
    return sb.toString();
}
```

In other words, although you'd probably *expect* to either see "x" or "" as the result, you could see "null". To fix that, you can read each value from the array just *once*:

```
final StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(totLength);
for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
    String value = strings[i];
    if (value != null) {
        sb.append(value);
    }
}
```

You may still see an array which is half way through being changed (e.g. if one thread is changing `{"x", "y"}` to `{"a", "b"}` you may see "xb" as the result), but you won't get a spurious "null".

Comment: Fascinating.  Somehow I didn't realize that the varargs method signature collapsed to the array at compile time.  I thought it was a type erasure situation, so you could only call a varags method.  Nice.

Comment: Would StringBuffer fix the problem in this scenario?

Comment: If you wanted a fast concat (for many `String`s), you'd want to use a correctly sized `char[]` instead of a `StringBuilder`. In order for the length to be guaranteed consistent you'd need to clone the array (or throw an exception if the length wasn't what you expected).

Comment: @Berlin: No, StringBuffer wouldn't change the problem at all, because it's reading from the string array which is the issue.

Answer (score 5):

That should be Thread Safe, as the Strings being passed in are immutable. and assuming you create `totLength` within the method, everything else is local .

EDIT:

as [Jon Skeet points out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1537818/java-stringbuilder-static-method-and-possible-synchronization-issues/1537893#1537893), there is a chance that the vargs value could be passed in not only as a sequence of Strings (as my answer assumes), but also as a `String[]`.  In the latter case, there is the possibility for the array to be modified by another thread while you are processing.

Comment: Good answer on your part, bad timing on mine.

Comment: not much difference between the two, really - in content and timing.

Answer (score 4):

No, it's thread-safe as written(*).  Strings are immutable, so it doesn't matter if multiple threads call this.

(* for the code you show)

Answer (score 3):

This would also be threadsafe even if you weren't passing in immutable objects, because

- you're not altering any of the input parameters
- the only thing you're changing is limited to the local scope of the method.

Answer (score 0):

See John Skeet's answer for the array part.

As for the `StringBuilder`, it should be safe.  Because the `StringBuilder` is created inside the method, each call has its own `StringBuilder`.

[`StringBuilder`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html) itself is not synchronized, so if it existed before the static method call, you'd be better off using a [`StringBuffer`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuffer.html) instead.

Comment: Sharing a StringBuffer would not work.  If the calls to append() in different threads are interleaved, the strings will be mixed up (even if the StringBuffer itself is always in a consistent state.)